# Metro UI rating static is not working

Tags: jquery, css, microsoft-metro

I am using [Metro UI rating widget](http://metroui.org.ua/rating.html) in my web application show the user rating. When I use the `data-static = 'true'` it should not allow the user to add new rating as per document. But it's not data-static is not working.

I noticed rating css having `:not` selector for static attribute, I doubt that's not supporting by browser.

Here is the css rating widget using.

```
.rating:not(.static):hover > .star, .rating:not(.static):hover > .star:after { color: gold !important;}
.rating:not(.static) .star:hover ~ .star, .rating:not(.static) .star:hover ~ .star:after { color: gray !important;}
.rating:not(.static) .star:hover {color: gold !important;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="rating" id="rating" data-static="true"></div>
```

Can someone tell me how to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I found some hack solution, Metro UI rating widget providing `data-on-rate` callback event option, using this callback we can disable option add new rating.

```
<div class="rating" id="rating" data-static="true" data-on-rate="onStaticRate"></div>
    function onStaticRate(value, star, widget){
        return false;
    }
```